# How to use for loop in a Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use for loop (not foreach) on a Model but no model properties shows up when I put dot after 'Model'. Do you know why?

```
@model IEnumerable<JPK.Models.DocumentsModel>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

 @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
     {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].Account )   //it doesn't work here, after Model. no properties apppear
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].Account) //same here
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </td>
        </tr>
     }
}
```

Comment: IEnumerable doesn't support indexing. Either use an IList or a foreach

Comment: @HansKeﬆing yes, you are right. The issue is that I need to pass value from e.g. 75th row (in 'Account' column) to controller by clicking on 'Save' button (button is in the same row). That's why I need to use for. I used 'for' loop anyways but it doesn't work as well. Values returned to controller are nulls. I really don't know why it happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@foreach (var model in Model)
     {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model=> model.Account )   //it doesn't work here, after Model. no properties apppear
                @Html.DisplayFor(model=> model.Account) //same here
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </td>
        </tr>
     }
```

or you can try

```
@model JPK.Models.DocumentsModel[]
```

You can still use foreach operator OR IF you want to use your index for as it is now, change count to length:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Length; i++)
```

Only before calling the view in your controller convert model to array. You can convert like this:

```
var model=oldModel.ToArray();
return View(model);
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this before.The problem is that I need to pass value from those fields into controller. I have like 100 rows with values for Account. I need to pass values from given row (there's 'Save' button in this row as well which passes value from this field to controller). Unfortunately, the mothod shown above return null

Comment: I added the way you can  use your indexes if you need them for some reason. Pleasce check my edited answer.

Comment: unfortunately Length property is not available for 'Model'. Only Count. I use MVC 5 if it's a case (.NET Framework 4.7)

Comment: You have to change your model  from IEnumerable to Array - model JPK.Models.DocumentsModel[]

Comment: I changed it and nopw I can add .Length. The issue is that i can't add ```.ToArray();``` in my controller, 'docs' doesn't accept this method: ```public ActionResult Update(DocumentsModel docs){  //some code return RedirectToAction("Index");}```

Comment: You have to change to array a model in GET action that creates this form not in the POST

Comment: In Update action change Update(DocumentsModel docs) to Update(DocumentsModel[] docs) or if you  still want to use IEnumerable then change DocumentsModel to IEnumerable<DocumentsModel>

Comment: thanks for your help. Still sth doesn't work. I'll talk to developers in my company and maybe they'll help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 'model' parameter in your lambda, not the 'Model' object of the page:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].Account)
```

Comment: it still shows an error, it goes that you can't use indexes for IEnumerable

Answer (score 0):

You have to accept it as a List if you want to use it in a For loop.
If you have to use an IEnumerable you have to use a foreach loop with a counter.

Something like this.

```
@{var counter = 0}
@foreach (var modelItem  in Model)
 {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem.Account )   //it doesn't work here, after Model. no properties apppear
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.Account) //same here
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </td>
    @counter++
    </tr>
 }
```

Or you could use var index = Model.IndexOf(modelItem)

Comment: Ok, I used this kind of code. Unfortunately values from Account field (I used 'hidden for' as shown above) does not pass to controller. It's still null. Do you happen to know where the problem lies?

Comment: I think something might be wrong in your controller, what dose the post method look like?

Comment: It looks like: ```public ActionResult Update(DocumentsModel docs){  //some code return RedirectToAction("Index");}``` When I hover over 'docs' then I see nulls everywhere on object's properties

Comment: Of course ```[HttpPost]``` is above this controller